# Use querySelectorAll Method and Create Table on Click

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've been assigned to do the following by my professor:
Create an HTML file to implement the concept of document object model using
JavaScript.

- Use getElementById Method and write in an element
- Use getElementsTagName Method and Change color and add border to
  the elements
- Use getElementsByClassName Method and for one paragraph and
  heading having same class name, change alignment
- Use querySelectorAll Method and Create Table on Click

However I have no idea on how to implement the last one... Could I have some help please?

```js
function msg4(){
    var table = querySelectorAll("table");
    //alert("Testing...");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the table using the object using the code below

```
let mountains = [
  { name: "Monte Falco", height: 1658, place: "Parco Foreste Casentinesi" },
  { name: "Monte Falterona", height: 1654, place: "Parco Foreste Casentinesi" },
  { name: "Poggio Scali", height: 1520, place: "Parco Foreste Casentinesi" },
  { name: "Pratomagno", height: 1592, place: "Parco Foreste Casentinesi" },
  { name: "Monte Amiata", height: 1738, place: "Siena" }
];

function generateTableHead(table, data) {
  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let row = thead.insertRow();
  for (let key of data) {
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    let text = document.createTextNode(key);
    th.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(th);
  }
}

function generateTable(table, data) {
  for (let element of data) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    for (key in element) {
      let cell = row.insertCell();
      let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
      cell.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
}

let table = document.querySelector("table");
let data = Object.keys(mountains[0]);
generateTableHead(table, data);
generateTable(table, mountains);
```